# Graph theory problem with friends

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

There are 9 people and for every 3 people, 2 of them are mutual friends. Please show that there exist 4 people out of the 9 who are all mutual friends.

Comment: This is equivalent to the fact that $R(3,4) \le 9$.  Take a look at Ramsey numbers.  Do you want a proof of this?

Comment: Yeah I'd appreciate a proof of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Recall the handshake lemma: the number of odd vertices must be even.  If $|G| = 9$, then take an even vertex $v$ (one must exist since otherwise there are $9$ odd vertices).  $d(v)$ must be one of $0,2,4,6,8$.

If $d(v) \ge 6$, then take all the neighbors of $v$.  Since $R(3,3) = 6$, then there must be an independent set of $3$ vertices (in which case we are done) or $3$ vertices which are mutually adjacent, so form a clique of order $4$ with $v$.

If $d(v) \le 4$, then take all $4$ non-neighbors of $v$.  Either these form a clique of order $4$ or there are two non-adjacent vertices, which together with $v$ form an independent set of order $3$.

This proves that $R(3,4) \le 9$.

Comment: Some notes: a *clique* is a set where any two vertices are adjacent, and an independent set is a set where no two vertices are adjacent.  You can prove $R(3,3) \le 6$ by a similar method, looking at the degrees of vertices (take any vertex--it must have $3$ neighbors or $3$ non-neighbors).